# Pashut Daf Yomi in 30 minutes

Tags: torah-study, daf-yomi

My friend works a 9-5 job (lawyer in New York, New York). He's been through Yeshiva (Mesivta & Beis Medresh) and started off married in Kollel. He now works and has had a hard time learning the Daf due to lack of time. He's tried many shuirim and has tried b'chavrusah. So, does anyone know of a Pashut Gemara Rashi Daf Yomi shuir in 30 minutes or less?

Comment: R' Eli Stefansky has an 8 minute daf yomi shiur which can be watched live or recorded. They also have a Whatsapp group. https://www.8minutedaf.com/

Comment: @eyl327 thats for chazarah only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem. Someone sent me this shuir and it was clear and under 30 minutes. Have your friend try this out. Hatzlacha Rabbah!

**https://chat.whatsapp.com/IltfkmD76kX8RQuv4i0bjN**

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that out.

Comment: Checked it out. Awesome. Thank you. @Falsemessiah